# Extension of an Array in Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, extension-methods

```
extension Array{

    func addBonus(addFunc:([Int])->([Int])) ->[Int]{
        return addFunc(self)//error in this line

    }
}
var empSalArray:[Int] = [2500,1300,1244,3412,5432,1223]
var empBonusAddedArry = empSalArray.addBonus{ arr -> [Int] in

    var temp = [Int]()
    for val in arr{
        temp.append(val+1000)
    }
    return temp
}
print(empBonusAddedArry)
```

Wanted to create an extension of Array..so that i can call as sort

```
array.sort(){}
```

However returns error as

> Cannot convert value of type Array to expected argument type
>   [Int].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addFunc(self)` in your extension method does not compile because the array need  not be an array of `Int` elements.

In this case, it is easy to fix:

```
extension Array {

    func addBonus(addFunc:([Element])->([Element])) ->[Element]{
        return addFunc(self)
    }
}
```

where `Element` is the generic placeholder type for the array.

Alternatively, you could consider to define the extension method
as

```
extension Array{
    func addBonus(addFunc:(Element)-> Element) ->[Element]{
        return self.map(addFunc)
    }
}
```

where a transform function for an array *element* instead of the 
entire array is passed:

```
var empSalArray:[Int] = [2500,1300,1244,3412,5432,1223]
var empBonusAddedArry = empSalArray.addBonus { amount in amount + 1000 }
print(empBonusAddedArry)
```

Of course you would get the same result with the built-in
`map()` method:

```
var empSalArray:[Int] = [2500,1300,1244,3412,5432,1223]
var empBonusAddedArry = empSalArray.map { amount in amount + 1000 }
print(empBonusAddedArry)
```

Comment: i was thinking of that..but intially trying to solve this functional way..passing functions around :)

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER: See update. Choose whatever you like best!

Comment: yes..there are tons to choose..but which one should i consider for performance...i think i should not use map?

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER: How large are the arrays, and how often is the transformation done? Is this operation a performance bottleneck for your code? – Start with the simplest solution and then profile the performance. *Then* optimize where necessary.